# Inovking an action from a parent in a child class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, architecture

I'm trying to create a kind of interactables system, where you can have collectible elements and interactable elements, where the collectible elements simply adds to your inventory once entered a collider, and the interactable elements need to have some feedback (user input) to be added

Here is the BaseInteractable class:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SphereCollider))]
public abstract class BaseInteractable : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    public enum Collectiblestate
    {
        Collected,
        NotCollected
    }

    protected Collectiblestate _collectibleState = Collectiblestate.NotCollected;
    public static event Action<IInteractable> OnInteractedItem;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) => OnItemInteracted();

    // This this function comes from the interface
    public virtual void OnItemInteracted() => OnInteractedItem?.Invoke(this);
}
```

Here is the StandardCollectible class:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class StandardCollectible : BaseInteractable
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _collectibleImage = default;

    public override void OnItemInteracted()
    {
        base.OnItemInteracted();
        _collectibleState = Collectiblestate.Collected;
        _collectibleImage.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

And here the StandardInteractable class:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class StandardInteractable : BaseInteractable
{
    public static event Action OnInteractThresholdReached;

    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _interactKey = KeyCode.L;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _collectibleImage = default;
    public override void OnItemInteracted()
    {
        //this is a notice for the canvas, to display a UI showing the interaction key
        OnInteractThresholdReached?.Invoke();

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(_interactKey))
        {
            // Here I am trying to call the interact item action
            base.OnInteractedItem?.Invoke(this);

            _collectibleState = Collectiblestate.Collected;
            _collectibleImage.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with this line right here on the StandardInteractable class:

`base.OnInteractedItem?.Invoke(this);`

I can't seem to invoke the Action from the parent class, and I'm not really finding any helpful information about it, because I don't want to subscribe StandardInteractable to the event, I want to Invoke it when the button is pressed.

Is this actually possible?

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: I believe the issue is from the OnItemInteracted method being called only on trigger enter.  This will only happen once, and therefore cannot "wait" for the input key down.  You may want to separate the systems since one needs an update loop and the other is trigger based.

Comment: If you add on trigger exit, the interactable can check if it is still in the trigger zone when input happens.  The interactable needs a bool set to true in enter and false in exit for determining if still in the trigger zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a class event in a derived class is not possible like that in C#. There is a common workaround for that by raising the base class event.

Simply create a method in `BaseInteractable` and invoke the event there. Then you can call this method from the derived class.

Here is the official MS explanation for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-raise-base-class-events-in-derived-classes

Update (added code example):
BaseInteractable.cs

```cs
protected void RaiseOnInteractedItem(StandardInteractable standardInteractable)
{
    OnInteractedItem?.Invoke(this);
}
```

StandardInteractable.cs

```cs
if(Input.GetKeyDown(_interactKey))
{
    // Here I am trying to call the interact item action
    RaiseOnInteractedItem(this);

    _collectibleState = Collectiblestate.Collected;
    _collectibleImage.SetActive(false);
}
```